# Tenemos oportunidad de crear nuestra propia encuesta para desarrolladores. ¿Les interesa?

Tags: discusión, encuesta-para-desarrolladores

El sitio en inglés tiene su encuesta "[Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017)" anualmente.  No se ha podido incluir todavía a los sitios internacionales pero he podido convencer a los directores a que nos permitan tener nuestra propia encuesta diseñada por nosotros para nosotros.

Si es algo que les interesa crear, tenemos tiempo para hacerlo.  Me gustaría lanzar esto a mitades de diciembre.  Lo haríamos cuidadosamente y al final les mostraría los datos para poder analizar la información.  Pero antes de empezar, necesito avisarles sobre algunas cosas.

1. Casi siempre las encuestas tienen un alcance limitado siendo que los que la tomarían serían probablemente los más activos aquí.  Queremos datos que representen a la comunidad entera así que sería para nuestro beneficio el poder anunciar y convencer a todos los que podamos de que la tomen. Si no, los resultados pueden ser parciales.
2. Podemos preguntar lo que queramos pero, ¿qué es lo que nos interesaría conocer más que nada? Hay pensar bien las preguntas.
3. Si decidimos hacer esto, los resultados se los enseñaría salvo que existan datos personales que no serian aptos para compartir.

Vamos a ver entonces si esto les apetece o no. Dejaré dos respuestas - una con un Sí y la otra con No.  Voten por la que les guste más.  Si prefieren el Sí, seguimos al siguiente paso y formulamos las preguntas. Si prefieren No, dejamos las cosas tal y como están.

---

## Decisión Final:

No tendremos una encuesta este año dado a que no parece existir el interés necesario para crearla. Gracias a todos los que participaron y nos dieron sus votos.

Comment: ¿Para qué segmentar? Una encuesta es más representativa si tiene un mayor número de encuestados... No entiendo la lógica en pensar en crear una encuesta diferente. ¿Por qué no traducir la encuesta de SO, permitiendo cruzar datos con otros países e idiomas? ¿No sería mucho más interesante ese resultado? ¿No sería más interesante poder analizar resultados según el idioma en que se respondió? Creo que la idea de SOes no es reinventar la rueda sino simplemente usarla con otros hábitos y costumbres. A lo sumo, pensaría en duplicar las preguntas sobre el uso de SO agregando el uso de SOes.

Answer (score 19):

## No vale la pena.

Pienso que una encuesta para nuestra comunidad no es una buena idea por ahora. Yo voto en contra.

Comment: Voto por el NO. Estamos necesitados de tiempo de Juan M para muchas cosas que son más importantes que esto. Abrir un frente más no hará más que ralentizar la implementación de muchas de las propuestas y resolución de bugs que se están acumulando.

Comment: @fedorqui He estado ayudando a la comunidad japonesa y a la portuguesa ya que se encuentran sin CM por el momento. Se que no he podido estar presente mucho últimamente y he querido estar más tiempo aquí. Me siento muy mal por eso.  Empezaré a dedicarle más tiempo a nuestros asuntos muy pronto pero les pido un poco de paciencia para que pueda estabilizar el rollo de las otras comunidades.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Juan. Desgraciadamente, observo que casi siempre estamos faltos de recursos y, al menos a mí, me cunde la sensación de que no hay guía clara de qué es importante y necesario, ni de cuáles son las prioridades. Ya te comenté en correo privado hace meses que hay muchas cosas pendientes de respuesta y parece que lanzar una propuesta aqui en Meta es predicar en el desierto. Propongo mayor transparencia, entradas explicativas de todo esto en el blog y, ojalá, algún tipo de [encuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354125/1983854) para decidir cuáles son las prioridades.

Comment: Lo ideal es que al inicio de la encuesta actual se puede escoger el idioma y todo el contenido este traducido. No tendría sentido duplicar esfuerzos y menos generar preguntas diferentes, si el objetivo es representar mejor a aquellas personas que no llenan la encuesta por temas de idioma

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz creo que Juan no habla de un problema de traduccion, si no de un tema de idiosincracias pq las comunidades son diferentes y pueden tener diferentes necesidades. Sin embargo estoy de acuerdo con fedorqui, hay miles de cosas para hacer, antes que una encuesta, por que ya de por si hay montones de cosas para arreglar que no se hacen por falta de tiempo.

Comment: El punto 2 es consecuencia del hecho que son encuestas diferentes, es decir ya que tecnológicamente es otra encuesta, no está limitado a que sean las mismas preguntas. Pero no es el objetivo. El objetivo de Stackoverflow al sacar los sitios internacionales es llegar a más personas donde antes no se podía. De la misma manera si ahora la encuesta está sesgada por temas de idioma lo mejor es que se considere la traducción lo antes posible para obtener una muestra más representativa.

Comment: Por otro lado es cierto que somos una comunidad diferente, y por lo tanto podemos tener actividades diferentes, pero realmente eso solo es parcialmente cierto. No somos por ejemplo futbol.stackexchange.com con otra temática y por lo tanto otras preguntas sino que somo parte de la comunidad global de stackoverflow con las mismas caraterísticas e inquitudes que todos, muy independiente del caracter regional de las comunidades que actualmente están un poco mas asiladas entre sí debido al idioma.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Tienes toda la razón pero no vamos a poder hacer eso este año.  La plataforma que usaremos para la encuesta no permite hacer esos cambios - aunque sí se hará en frances y aleman esta vez solamente... El año que viene es casi un hecho que lo tendremos en español también.

Comment: @JuanM hay algo que no entiendo: ¿una plataforma no permite agregar un nuevo idioma? Vamos, estamos entre programadores, todos sabemos el motivo. Perdón, pero no parecería un motivo concreto, menos aún si se va a hacer en francés y alemán... Esto parecería ser un tema de recursos y la intención (o falta de) para asignarlos... Según Jon Ericson, *[Ideally, we'd have surveys that are more broad than our core programmer population](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge/341460#comment438527_341460)... Comprendo que sea ...

Comment: [cont.] la visión generalizada de SO incluirlo, pero que no haya recursos (o ROI para ser preciso) en esto, y que se postergue. No me parece mal, hay cosas más importantes que una traducción. Sólo que no diría que es un problema de la plataforma... Quizás es hora de poner sobre la mesa qué recursos hay y cómo fijamos prioridades, qué le importa realmente a la comunidad (-y sé que lo estás empezando a hacer, leí [tu publicación en el blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/30/lo-que-ha-sucedido-este-ano/?cb=1) y me pareció un buen paso)

Comment: @Mariano Lo que les conte es la misma información que recibí. No se ha alterado nada al respecto.  Entiendo que no es imposible el añadir otro lenguaje pero las razones no me las han compartido aparte de que el interés esta por ahora solamente en tener esos lenguajes ya mencionados (para la encuesta "oficial"). Esto no quiere decir que no podemos tener una encuesta separada, pero la oficial no incluye el castellano.

Answer (score 12):

## Sí vale la pena.

Me parece que una encuesta para nuestra comunidad podría ser de beneficio para nosotros.  Yo voto afirmativamente.

Comment: Si bien en el titio en Idioma Inglés la mayoría de los resultados son enfocados a la comunidad de StackOverflow, también pueden responder la encuesta personas externas al sitio. Yo considero esto como una oportunidad para captar más personas y llamar la atención de las comunidades de programación latinas. Creo que a todos nos gustaría saber los cruces de información de rangos salariales, país donde trabaja, años de experiencia, número de lenguajes de programación que maneja y las razones por las que participa o participaría alguien en stack overflow en español.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Estoy de acuerdo, pienso que nos beneficiaría mucho tener esta información pero, bueno, esperemos un poco más de tiempo para ver que dice la gente.