# ¿De qué trata y para qué sirve la encuesta para desarrolladores?

Tags: discusión, encuesta-para-desarrolladores

Acabo de entrar al sitio y se me presenta en la parte superior este aviso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¡Está de vuelta! Toma hoy la encuesta del 2018 para desarrolladores »

Me gustaría saber:

- ¿Qué es la encuesta para desarrolladores? ¿De qué trata?
- ¿Qué fines tiene?

Busqué en Meta alguna pregunta que respondiera a mis dudas y no encontré nada, hay una pregunta de @JuanM que trata sobre esta encuesta: [Tenemos oportunidad de crear nuestra propia encuesta para desarrolladores. ¿Les interesa?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2847/29967), pero la misma no responde a mis dudas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La encuesta para desarrolladores es un [esfuerzo que Stack Overflow ha realizado por 7 años - este siendo el octavo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/08/take-2018-developer-survey/). Se les pide a los desarrolladores que visitan nuestro sitio a que respondan preguntas sobre lenguajes de programación, preferencias de carrera, experiencia de trabajo, etc. Este año se han agregado preguntas sobre la inteligencia artificial, las éticas de programación, y otros temas interesantes.

El final que lleva la encuesta es el poder recolectar información sobre estas areas de tecnología para poder aprender sobre las inclinaciones y las específicas de ellas.  La información recolectada es ofrecida gratuitamente al publico bajo el Open Database License que nos permite compartir lo que hayamos encontrado.  Esta información se puede descargar al finalizar nuestro análisis interno.  Los enlaces los puedo compartir en cuanto estén disponibles.

Para ver los resultados de la encuesta del 2017, [pueden buscar aquí](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017).  Siendo que la información es global, podemos contribuir nuestras experiencias y conocimiento para poder afectar y mejorar los resultados.  La encuesta esta en inglés, no se ha traducido al español/castellano.

¡Los animo a que tomen parte de la encuesta para poder representar nuestra comunidad y nuestros países también!

Comment: Agregando a lo que Juan dice, también es interesante destacar que [los datos están abiertos para que cualquiera los baje y juegue con ellos](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/)